# strings are missing when i try to print(response.text)

Tags: python, http, get, request, response

I am learning & working with python from couple of days.
In my source code need to read the http contents.
I am trying to scrape http using request.get(httplink).
For debugging purpose i am trying to display all the contents of http using print(response.text).
But i could see few of the strings are not displayed when i run the code.
My question is print(response.text) will displays all the strings from the http page??Please someone answer to my question as i am not able to proceed further.

Comment: Can you add some code examples?

Comment: Please share the code snippet and expectation

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Using linux Putty

Comment: from lxml import html
import requests
import json


m_page = requests.get(httpurl)
print(m_page.text)

Answer (score 0):

The [text](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response) property of Response object is just content, but decoded according to headers. First of all try check out **content** field and find missing strings there. This is about output (console), i presume :)